# Is data really copied four times in R's replacement functions?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

Consider this variable

```
a = data.frame(x=1:5,y=2:6)
```

When I use a replacement function to change the first element of `a`, how many times
is memory of the same size of `a` copied?

```
tracemem(a)
"change_first_element<-" = function(x, value) {
  x[1,1] = value
  return(x)
}
change_first_element(a) = 3
# tracemem[0x7f86028f12d8 -> 0x7f86028f1498]: 
# tracemem[0x7f86028f1498 -> 0x7f86028f1508]: change_first_element<- 
# tracemem[0x7f86028f1508 -> 0x7f8605762678]: [<-.data.frame [<- change_first_element<- 
# tracemem[0x7f8605762678 -> 0x7f8605762720]: [<-.data.frame [<- change_first_element<-
```

There are four copy operations. I know that R doesn't mutate objects or pass by reference (yes, there are exceptions), but why are there four copies? Shouldn't one copy be enough?

*Part 2:*

If I call the replacement function differently, there are only three copy operations?

```
tracemem(a)
a = `change_first_element<-`(a,3)
# tracemem[0x7f8611f1d9f0 -> 0x7f8607327640]: change_first_element<- 
# tracemem[0x7f8607327640 -> 0x7f8607327758]: [<-.data.frame [<- change_first_element<- 
# tracemem[0x7f8607327758 -> 0x7f8607327800]: [<-.data.frame [<- change_first_element<-
```

Comment: This is sort of a side note, but I think you'll get a clearer picture of copying by using `tracemem` and just looking at assignment and subsetting functions not wrapped in your own function.

Comment: Thanks joran. I didn't know about `tracemem`. I noticed that using a replace function in the normal way, `tracemem` gave me four lines (presumably four copies?). Calling the replacement function the nonstandard way gave me three lines. I'll someone correct me in an answer if I was using `inspect` the wrong way.

Comment: I don't think you were necessarily using `inspect` wrong, I just thought the question could be more clearly posed using `tracemem`, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I changed the question to use `tracemem`.

Comment: This is how I see it: (1.) Call `tracemem`, (2.) create function (3 and 4) run function on data frame.  I could be incredibly wrong though. :)

Comment: I only know enough to speculate a bit about these sorts of things, but [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html) is pretty good background reading.

Comment: The best I can contribute is that I see three copies when calling `a[1,1] <- 3`: one for the function argument, one for modifying the class inside `[<-.data.frame` and one for the value change itself. Note that this is specific to data frames; doesn't happen with lists.

Comment: ...calling it via `'[<-'(a,1,1,3)` skips the initial copy, for reasons I can't fully explain, maybe having to do with how the REPL has to interpret things (?), and in the most general sense probably has some dangerous side effects that make that syntax dangerous for some hard to predict edge cases.

Comment: Read Simon Urbanek's and Luke Tierney's answer from [this post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html).

Comment: @Arun, that's super-informative. Feels like transcribing the important parts of it here would be the canonical answer (but that also sounds like a fair bit of work)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

NOTE: Unless otherwise specified, all explanations below are valid for R versions < 3.1.0. There are great improvements made in R v3.1.0, which is also briefly touched upon here.

To answer your first question, *"why four copies and shouldn't one be enough?"*, we'll begin by quoting the relevant part from [R-internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html) first:

> A 'named' value of 2, NAM(2), means that the object must be duplicated before being changed. (Note that this does not say that it is necessary to duplicate, only that it should be duplicated whether necessary or not.) A value of 0 means that it is known that no other SEXP shares data with this object, and so it may safely be altered.
>
> A value of 1 is used for situations like `dim(a) <- c(7, 2)` where in principle two copies of a exist for the duration of the computation as (in principle)
> `a <-` dim<-`(a, c(7, 2))` but for no longer, and so some primitive functions can be optimized to avoid a copy in this case.

#### NAM(1):

Let's start with `NAM(1)` objects. Here's an example:

```
x <- 1:5 # (1)
.Internal(inspect(x))
# @10374ecc8 13 INTSXP g0c3 [NAM(1)] (len=5, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5
tracemem(x)
# [1] "<0x10374ecc8>"

x[2L] <- 10L # (2)
.Internal(inspect(x))
# @10374ecc8 13 INTSXP g0c3 [MARK,NAM(1),TR] (len=5, tl=0) 1,10,3,4,5
```

What's happening here? We created an integer vector using `:`, it being a primitive, resulted in a NAM(1) object. And when we used `[<-` on that object, the value got changed in-place (note that the pointers are identical, (1) and (2)). This is because `[<-` being a primitive knows quite well how to handle its inputs and is optimised for a no-copy in this scenario.

```
y = x # (3)
.Internal(inspect(x))
# @10374ecc8 13 INTSXP g0c3 [MARK,NAM(2),TR] (len=5, tl=0) 1,10,3,4,5

x[2L] <- 20L # (4)
.Internal(inspect(x))
# tracemem[0x10374ecc8 -> 0x10372f328]:
# @10372f328 13 INTSXP g0c3 [NAM(1),TR] (len=5, tl=0) 1,20,3,4,5
```

Now the same assignment results in a copy, why? By doing (3), the 'named' field gets incremented to NAM(2) as more than one object is pointing to the same data. Even if `[<-` is optimised, the fact that it's a `NAM(2)` means that the object *must* be duplicated. That's why it's now again a `NAM(1)` object after the assignment. That's because, call to `duplicate` sets `named` to 0 and the new assignment bumps it back to 1.

> Note: Peter Dalgaard explains this case nicely [in this link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html) as to why `x = 2L` results in NAM(2) object.

---

#### NAM(2):

Now let's return to *your* question on calling `*<-` on a `data.frame` which is a `NAM(2)` object.

The first question then is, why is `data.frame()` a `NAM(2)` object? Why not a NAM(1) like the earlier case  `x <- 1:5`? Duncan Murdoch answers this very nicely on the [same post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html):

> `data.frame()` is a plain R function, so it is treated no differently than any user-written function.  On the other hand, the internal function that implements the `:` operator is a *primitive*, so it has complete control over its return value, and it can set `NAMED` in the most efficient way.

This means any attempt to change the value would result in triggering a `duplicate` (a *deep copy*). From `?tracemem`:

> ... any copying of the object by the C function `duplicate` produces a message to standard output.

So a message from `tracemem` helps understand the number of copies. To understand the first line of your `tracemem` output, let's construct the function `f<-`, which does no actual replacement. Also, let's construct a `data.frame` big enough so that we can measure the time taken for a single copy of that `data.frame`.

```
## R v 3.0.3
`f<-` = function(x, value) {
    return(x) ## no actual replacement
}

df <- data.frame(x=1:1e8, y=1:1e8) # 762.9 Mb
tracemem(df) # [1] "<0x7fbccd2f4ae8>"

require(data.table)
system.time(copy(df)) 
# tracemem[0x7fbccd2f4ae8 -> 0x7fbccd2f4ff0]: copy system.time 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.609   0.484   1.106 

system.time(f(df) <- 3)
# tracemem[0x7fbccd2f4ae8 -> 0x7fbccd2f4f10]: system.time 
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.608   0.480   1.101
```

I've used the function `copy()` from `data.table` (which basically calls the C `duplicate` function). The times for copying are more or less identical. So, the first step is clearly a *deep copy*, even if it did *nothing*.

This explains the first two verbose messages from `tracemem` in your post:

> (1) From the global environment we called `f(df) <- 3)`. Here's *one* copy.
> (2) From within the function `f<-`, another assignment `x[1,1] <- 3` which'll call the `[<-` (and hence the `[<-.data.frame` function). That makes the *second* copy immediately.

Finding the rest of the copies is easy with a `debugonce()` on `[<-.data.frame`. That is, doing:

```
debugonce(`[<-`)
df <- data.frame(x=1:1e8, y=1:1e8)
`f<-` = function(x, value) {
    x[1,1] = value
    return(x)
}
tracemem(df)
f(df) = 3

# first three lines:

# tracemem[0x7f8ba33d8a08 -> 0x7f8ba33d8d50]:      (1)
# tracemem[0x7f8ba33d8d50 -> 0x7f8ba33d8a78]: f<-  (2)
# debugging in: `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1L, 1L, value = 3L)
```

By hitting *enter*, you'll find the other two copies to be inside this function:

```
# debug: class(x) <- NULL
# tracemem[0x7f8ba33d8a78 -> 0x7f8ba3cd6078]: [<-.data.frame [<- f<-     (3)

# debug: x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj
# tracemem[0x7f8ba3cd6078 -> 0x7f882c35ed40]: [<-.data.frame [<- f<-     (4)
```

Note that `class` is primitive but it's being called on a NAM(2) object. I suspect that's the reason for the copy there. And the last copy is inevitable as it modifies the column.

So, there you go.

---

Now a small note on `R v3.1.0`:

> I also tested the same in `R V3.1.0`. `tracemem` provides all four lines. However, the only *time-consuming* step is (4). IIUC, the remaining cases, all due to `[<-` / `class<-` should be triggering a *shallow copy* instead of *deep copy*. What's awesome is that, even in (4), only that column that's being modified seems to be *deep copied*. R 3.1.0 has great improvements!
>
> This means `tracemem` provides output due to *shallow copy* too - which is a bit confusing since the documentation doesn't explicitly state that and makes it hard to tell between a shallow and deep copy, except by measuring time. Perhaps it's my (incorrect) understanding. Feel free to correct me.

---

On your part 2, I'll quote Luke Tierney from [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html):

> Calling a `foo<-` function directly is not a good idea unless you really understand what is going on in the assignment mechanism in general and in the particular `foo<-` function. It is definitely not something to be done in routine programming unless you like unpleasant surprises.

But I am unable to tell if these unpleasant surprises extend to an object that's already `NAM(2)`. Because, Matt was calling it on a `list`, which is a primitive and therefore NAM(1), and calling `foo<-` directly wouldn't increment it's 'named' value.

But, the fact that R v3.1.0 has great improvements should already convince you that such a function call is not necessary anymore.

HTH.

PS: Feel free to correct me (and help me shorten this answer if possible) :).

---

**Edit:** I seem to have missed the point about a copy being reduced when calling `f<-` directly as spotted under comment. It's pretty easy to see by using the function Simon Urbanek used in the post (that's linked multiple times now):

```
# rm(list=ls()) # to make sure there' no other object in your workspace
`f<-` <- function(x, value) {
    print(ls(env = parent.frame()))
}

df <- data.frame(x=1, y=2)
tracemem(df) # [1] "<0x7fce01a65358>"

f(df) = 3
# tracemem[0x7fce0359b2a0 -> 0x7fce0359ae08]: 
# [1] "*tmp*" "df"    "f<-"  

df <- data.frame(x=1, y=2)
tracemem(df) # [1] "<0x7fce03c505c0>"
df <- `f<-`(df, 3)
# [1] "df"  "f<-"
```

As you can see, in the first method there's an object `*tmp*` that's being created, which is not, in the second case. And it seems like this creation of `*tmp*` object for a `NAM(2)` input object triggers a copy of the input before `*tmp*` gets assigned to the function argument. But that's as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: Neat! So I wasn't too far off I guess. I wasn't quite able to pick up from this why the calling method seems to remove one of the copies (i.e. `a[1,1] <- 3` versus `'[<-(a,1,1,3)`). Did I miss that?