# Efficient Way to Convert Vector of Distances to Distance Object in R (ideally without creating a full distance matrix)

Tags: r, matrix, vector, distance

I have a vector of distances which I get from some other procedure and want to convert it to a `dist` object in the `R` language .

Below I give an example how such a vector *looks like*: `distVector` is computed in the same way said other procedure computes the distance vector. Ideally, I would like to transform this vector into a distance matrix (`dist` object) without wasting resources.

I think I could just transform it to a matrix by copying it as upper triangular and lower triangular matrix, setting the diagonals to 0, and dealing with the fact that it is sort of `upside down` compared to the `dist` object structure (compare outputs below). Then again, first creating a full matrix and then (probably?) reducing it again to a vector in the `dist` object seems wasteful to me. Is there a better way?

Example code (note: I cannot change how `distVector` is computed):

```
rawData<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1.1,1,1,1,1,1.2,2,2,2,2.2,2,2,2,2.2,2.2,3,3,3,3.4,3,3),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE);

distVector<-integer(0);
for(i in 1:dim(rawData)[1]) {
  for(j in (i+1):dim(rawData)[1]) {
    a <- (rawData[i,]-rawData[j,]);
    distVector <- c(distVector, sqrt(a %*% a));
  }
}

print(distVector)
print(dist(rawData))
```

Output: Compare `distVector` to the output of the `dist` function, it is upside down)

```
> print(distVector)
 [1] 0.1000000 0.2000000 1.7320508 1.8547237 1.9697716 3.4641016 3.7094474 0.2236068 1.6763055
[10] 1.7916473 1.9209373 3.4073450 3.6455452 1.6248077 1.7549929 1.8547237 3.3526109 3.6055513
[19] 0.2000000 0.2828427 1.7320508 1.9899749 0.3464102 1.6248077 1.8547237 1.5099669 1.8000000
[28] 0.4000000

> print(dist(rawData))
          1         2         3         4         5         6         7
2 0.1000000                                                            
3 0.2000000 0.2236068                                                  
4 1.7320508 1.6763055 1.6248077                                        
5 1.8547237 1.7916473 1.7549929 0.2000000                              
6 1.9697716 1.9209373 1.8547237 0.2828427 0.3464102                    
7 3.4641016 3.4073450 3.3526109 1.7320508 1.6248077 1.5099669          
8 3.7094474 3.6455452 3.6055513 1.9899749 1.8547237 1.8000000 0.4000000
```

Many thanks,
  Thomas.

Comment: creating the matrix seems reasonable to me ... `mat <- matrix(NA, ncol=dim(rawData)[1], nrow=dim(rawData)[1]) ; mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- distVector`

Comment: That's a short and nice answer. I am not yet familiar with `R`. This I wonder how the memory consumption of this would be? Will this create a full m*m matrix, fill its lower triangle with my data, and then extract this lower triangle again in my subsequent `as.dist` call? Or would it just somehow create an empty container for a m*m matrix or something, not consuming much memory? Either way, your method seems to be feasible to me. Thanks ^_^

Comment: Sorry i dont know about R's memory usage / copying of objects etc .  There a quite a few questions on SO that have looked at such stuffs though -- [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898969/is-data-really-copied-four-times-in-rs-replacement-functions) was my fist search hit.. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tracemem.html might be useful

Comment: You could hide some of the looping code with `combn(1:nrow(rawData),2, function(x) {o <- rawData[x[1],] - rawData[x[2],]; c(sqrt(o %*% o))} )`

Comment: @user20650: ugh, that's much to read ^_^. Well, unless there is a simpler, non-matrix-creating solution, I will take your suggestion, as it is very compact code-wise. In case no non-matrix-creating-solution shows up until tomorrow, if you want you can copy-paste your comment as answer and I will accept it. (Basically, it is an answer.)

Comment: @thelatemail: I get `distVector` from elsewhere, the code here is just an example so people can how it looks like and what its elements represent. Thus, this part of the code does not need to be optimized. Still, being new to `R`, from your comment, I learned something useful and new to me. Thanks for showing the `combn` function and this inline-function-definition method :-)

Comment: ha.. lots to read but its good stuff ;p. It might be worth emphasising in your question title, that you are looking for an efficient way. Some people on SO / r tag that are knowledgeable of such stuffs

Comment: @user20650: noted, title changed. Thanks again.

Comment: Another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281593/large-distance-matrix-in-clustering/34281930#34281930) may be helpful, especially `dist` function can be performed w/ multithread easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the class to `dist`, but you also need to set the `Size` attribute to the number of rows in the full distance matrix:

```
> v=4:9;class(v)="dist";attr(v,"Size")=ceiling(sqrt(length(v)*2));v
  1 2 3
2 4
3 5 7
4 6 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
structure(x, class = 'dist',
          Size = Re(polyroot(c(-2*length(x),-1,1))[1]))
```

Where `x` is your `distVector`