# Unintentional memory address change in R data.table object

Tags: r, memory, data.table, bigdata

I have trouble with large data.table object in R.
I found that the memory address of data.table object is changed without copy or something in some situation. For example,

```
library(data.table)

create_dt <- function(nrow=5, ncol=5, propNA = 0.5){
  v <- runif(nrow * ncol)
  v[sample(seq_len(nrow*ncol), propNA * nrow*ncol)] <- NA
  data.table(matrix(v, ncol=ncol))
}
# helper function to make large data.table
# create_dt source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898969/is-data-really-copied-four-times-in-rs-replacement-functions

d0 = create_dt(3e5, 1058, 0.1)
tracemem(d0) #1 
d0[, new:=0][is.na(V1000), new1:=1]
table(d0$new1)
tracemem(d0) #2
```

Mostly, 2 tracemem(d0) print same address.
But sometimes, printed address is changed. 
And when this situation evoked, the data of all new1 column become to 0.
Because it is randomly happened, I could not make it fully reproducible.
But I had same problem with above code.

I think this situation is more frequently evoked when I use large memory in my notebook (ex. many chrome tab, many other application used in same time.)

I'm using windows 7 with RAM 64G, HDD 1T. and R 3.3.2, data.table 1.10.2 is used. The platform is x86_64-w64-mingw32.

Is anyone experience same problem with me? And is anyone know why this happened, and what is a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue even if I execute your code in an infinite loop. AFAIK, a copy would happen if adding a column makes the number of columns larger than `truelength(d0)`. That shouldn't happen with your example.

Comment: Thank you. I'll figure out how to make this problem more reproducible with example code. Thank you.