# Why does the extract method for data frames make two copies?

Tags: r, memory

I'm trying to get a better understanding of performance in for loops in R. I modified the example from Hadley's book [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html) but I'm still confused.

I have the following set-up, where the for loop goes over several random columns:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1e3), ncol = 10))
cols <- sample(names(df), 2)
tracemem(df)
```

I have a for loop that runs for every element of `cols`.

```
  for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
      df[[cols[i]]] <- 3.2
  }
```

I get the following list of copies.

```
tracemem[0x1c54040 -> 0x20e1470]: 
tracemem[0x20e1470 -> 0x20e17b8]: [[<-.data.frame [[<- 
tracemem[0x20e17b8 -> 0x20dc4b8]: [[<-.data.frame [[<- 
tracemem[0x20dc4b8 -> 0x20dc800]: 
tracemem[0x20dc800 -> 0x20dc8a8]: [[<-.data.frame [[<- 
tracemem[0x20dc8a8 -> 0x20dcaa0]: [[<-.data.frame [[<-
```

Hadley notes in his example:

> In fact, each iteration copies the data frame not once, not twice, but
>   three times! Two copies are made by [[.data.frame, and a further copy
>   is made because [[.data.frame is a regular function that increments
>   the reference count of x.

Can someone explain *why* the `[[<-.data.frame` method needs to make two copies?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the reason is the same as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23911746/324364) answer; namely you get one copy for changing the value and another copy from `class<-` at the end, since it is being called on a NAM(2) object at that point. That answer also suggests that R has improved things over time, so you're seeing both shallow & deep copies, and so not every "copy" necessarily incurs as large a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a complete answer to your question, but it's a start.

If you look in the R Language Definition, you'll see that `df[["name"]] <- 3.2` is implemented as

```
`*tmp*` <- df
df <- "[[<-.data.frame"(`*tmp*`, "name", value=3.2)
rm(`*tmp*`)
```

So one copy gets put into `*tmp*`.  If you call `debug("[[<-.data.frame")`, you'll see that it really does get called with an argument called `*tmp*`, and
`tracemem()` will show that the first duplication happens before you enter.

The function `[[<-.data.frame` is a regular function with a header like this:

```
function (x, i, j, value)
```

That function gets called as

```
`[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "name", value = 3.2)
```

Now there are three references to the dataframe:  `df` in the global environment, `*tmp*` in the internal code, and `x` in that function.   (Actually, there's an intermediate step where the generic is called, but it is a primitive, so it doesn't need to make a new reference.)

The class of `x` gets changed in the function; that triggers a copy.  Then one of the components of `x` is changed; that's another copy.  So that makes 3.

Just guessing, I'd say the reason for the first duplication is that a complicated replacement might refer to the original value, and it's avoiding the possibility of retrieving a partially modified value.

Comment: I think this is exactly right. Rather than complication though, Hadley’s book says the first duplication is because [[<-.data.frame “is a regular function that increments the reference count of x.” I’m going to have to dig more into the internal documentation to understand what that means.

Comment: @user21359:  That's not really an answer.  Incrementing the reference count means that the next modification will trigger a duplication, it doesn't trigger a duplication itself.  Hadley doesn't know what's happening here any more than you or I do.